# Is my proof of showing "$r^2+2rs+s^2$ is composite for all positive integer $r$ and $s$" correct?

Tags: solution-verification

Hi again a question on if my proof is correct, since the way it is written differs much with how the book proofs it..

**The Question given is :**
"$r^2+2rs+s^2$ is composite for all positive integer $r$ and $s$"

**Here's the proof I have written :**

Assume that $r$ and $s$ are particular integers 
It is given the number is $r^2+2rs+s^2$
It can be written as $r^2+2rs+s^2 = (r+s)\cdot(r+s)$ 
Let $m = (r +s)$ and $n=(r+s)$ not that $m,n$ are positive integers 
Hence, $\exists m,n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, such that $r^2+2rs+s^s = m \cdot n$ 
$\therefore r^2+2rs+s^2$ is composite

**This is the answer given in the solution book :**

It is given that, if r and s are both positive, i.e., $r>0, s>0$ 
Then, $r^2+2rs+s^2 = (r+s)^2 =(r+s)\cdot(r+s)$ 
$\therefore r^2+2rs+s^2$ is composite 
Since $r>0$ and $s>0$, then $r+s \neq 1$ 
By the definition of a composite number, the given number is composite

Comment: it is literally the same proof, you just forgot to check the (trivial) case that one of the brackets is 1, but otherwise, they are same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two differences that I can see.

One is that you chose to give two (different) notations $m,n$ for the two factors of $r+s$; the book proof is more concise and does not introduce new notation at all.

The other is you wrote "note that $m,n$ are positive integers", which is not sufficient to complete the proof. You also have to *note* that, and *prove* that $m,n \ne 1$; or, as the more concise book proof does, you have to prove that $r+s \ne 1$.

Comment: does this mean that if I would say; note that $m,n$ are integers and since $m>0$
 and $n>0$
, then $m+n\neq1$
 would be sufficient to prove that m and n are positive integers?

Comment: Yes, that would be fine.

Comment: I'll say that your latest comment points out one further difference in your proof and the book's proof: the book leaves it implicit that $r+s$ is a positive integer, whereas you spell that issue out in a bit more detail.

Comment: thanks you for the explanation. this will really help me in preparing for my exam :)