# Is my proof of showing "There is an integer $n$ such that $2n^2 - 5n + 2$ is prime" correct?

Tags: solution-verification

once again a question on if my proof is correct, since the way it is written differs much with how the book proofs it. I know that the $n$ chosen does not make much of a difference in this case, I am mostly doubting if the steps taken towards the conclusion are enough to prove $2n^2 - 5n + 2$ is prime

**The Question given is :**
"$\exists n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $2n^2 - 5n + 2$ is prime"

**Here's the proof I have written :**
Suppose an integer $n$

 Let $n = 0$

 Then by substitution $2n^2 - 5n + 2 = 2(0)^2-5(0)+2$

 $=0-0+2$

 $=2$, which is a prime number

 $\therefore \exists n \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $2n^2 - 5n + 2$ is prime, where $n=0$

**This is the answer given in the solution book :**

When $n = 3$,

Now put the value of $n = 3$ in equation $2n^2 - 5n + 2$,

This implies;

  $2n^2 - 5n + 2 = 2(3)^2-5(3)+2$

  $= 2(9)-15+2$

  $= 18-13$

  $= 5$

This implies;

 $2n^2 - 5n + 2 = 5$

Here, $5$ is a prime number.

So,$2n^2 - 5n + 2$ is also prime.

Hence proved, there is an integer $n$ such that $2n^2 - 5n + 2$ is prime.

Comment: One integer giving a prime is enough. Proof by inspection is the only way in such cases.

Comment: Yes your proof is correct. Are you sure the question does not ask for a positive integer?

Comment: $(x-2)(2x-1)$ helps I guess

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku Yes, I mostly questioned myself due to the fact they have more steps in between the beginning and the end. I thought I maybe lacked some steps in my proof.

Comment: The solutions are way too long. With $f(n)=2n^2-5n+2=(n-2)(2n-1)$ it is enough to say that $f(3)=5$ is prime, or $f(0)=2$ is prime, if $n=0$ is allowed. For all other $n$ the integer $f(n)$ is composite. Compare this with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4620193/is-my-proof-of-showing-r22rss2-is-composite-for-all-positive-integer-r).

Comment: In short, your proof is cumbersome, but correct , unless a positive integer is explicitely demanded.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for your feedback. I lack the ability to see what you are trying to show me with comparing this question, with the question you mentioned. Could you explain this in more detail?

Comment: @DietrichBurde $f(-1)=-1,$ which I would say is neither prime nor composite, but of course that still leaves $n=0$ and $n=3$ as the only witnesses of the conclusion.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Any feedback on the -1, then I can take this into account into future questions.

Comment: @Diceble Usually, only integers larger than $1$ are considered to be "composite" or "prime". We could extend this to negative integers smaller than $-1$ which is sometimes done. I have however never heard of "composite" or "prime" in context with $-1$ , $0$ or $1$. It is reasonable to consider those numbers to be neither because neither the units $-1$ and $1$ nor $0$ are prime elements in the ring $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: I don't know why the question was downvoted. I would call the proofs "painstaking" rather than cumbersome. A teacher might encourage such simple proofs to have this many steps when the student is new to writing proofs. When you have more experience you might just write, "When $n=0,$ $2n^2 - 5n + 2=2,$ which is prime, therefore there is an integer $n$ such that $2n^2 - 5n + 2$ is prime." For the right audience you might even stop at "which is prime".

Comment: @Peter Thank you for your further explanation

Comment: @DavidK I am indeed new to writing proofs, Thank you for showing another way which is a more experienced way of writing the same proof.

Comment: @Diceble Do not care about strange downvotes. I receive them often without an apparent reason or an explanation why it was downvoted.